# back button still working after disabling it in cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have implemented code so as to disable the android device back button but it isn't working. When i run my app and tap the back button, it simply exits. I have included cordova.js in my index.html file. What am i doing wrong?
here is my code:

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {  
      document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
          function onBackKeyDown(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
           } 

}, false);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <!--<link href="assets/ratchet/css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- <link href="assets/jqueryui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="maincontainer">

<script id="langue-tpl" type="text/template">
    <div id="mydialog" title="Beezlink"></div>
    <div class="sk-circle" id="proc"><div class="sk-circle1 sk-child"></div><div class="sk-circle2 sk-child"></div><div class="sk-circle3 sk-child"></div><div class="sk-circle4 sk-child"></div><div class="sk-circle5 sk-child"></div><div class="sk-circle6 sk-child"></div><div class="sk-circle7 sk-child"></div><div class="sk-circle8 sk-child"></div><div class="sk-circle9 sk-child"></div><div class="sk-circle10 sk-child"></div><div class="sk-circle11 sk-child"></div><div class="sk-circle12 sk-child"></div></div>
    <div class="contentwrap home">
   <div id="bodydiv">
    <!--
    <img src="assets/logo-symbol.png" class="home-logo" />
   <div>    
      <div class="form-group">
        <select id="langtr" class="form-control">        
              <option value="val_fr">Francais</option>
              <option value="val_english">English</option>
              <option value="val_spanish">Spanish</option>
              <option value="val_german">German</option>
          </select>
          <br/><button id="gobtn">OK</button>
      </div>
   </div>
   -->
  </div> 
</div>  
</script>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

<script src="lib/handlebars"></script>


<script type='application/javascript' src='lib/fastclick'></script>



<script src="lib/jquery"></script>

<script src="lib/jquery-ui"></script>

<script src="lib/jquery.alphanum"></script>

<script src="js/LangueView"></script>
<script src="js/app"></script>
<script src="js/disablerclick"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
// We use an "Immediate Function" to initialize the application to avoid leaving anything behind in the global scope
(function () {
    Handlebars.registerHelper('compare', function (lvalue, operator, rvalue, options) {

    var operators, result;

    if (arguments.length < 3) {
        //throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' a besoin de 2 parametres");
    }

    if (options === undefined) {
        options = rvalue;
        rvalue = operator;
        operator = "===";
    }

    operators = {
        '==': function (l, r) { return l == r; },
        '===': function (l, r) { return l === r; },
        '!=': function (l, r) { return l != r; },
        '!==': function (l, r) { return l !== r; },
        '<': function (l, r) { return l < r; },
        '>': function (l, r) { return l > r; },
        '<=': function (l, r) { return l <= r; },
        '>=': function (l, r) { return l >= r; },
        'typeof': function (l, r) { return typeof l == r; }
    };

    if (!operators[operator]) {
        //throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' ne connait pas l'operateur " + operator);
    }

    result = operators[operator](lvalue, rvalue);

    if (result) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }

});

 LangueView.prototype.template = Handlebars.compile($("#langue-tpl").html());
  $('body').html(new LangueView().render().$el);

            /* ---------------------------------- Local Variables ---------------------------------- */

      //  var pictureSource; // picture source
      //var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value
      // Wait for device API libraries to load
      //
  /*var service = new EmployeeService();
     service.initialize().done(function () {
     $('body').html(new HomeView(service).render().$el);
    });*/

    /* --------------------------------- Event Registration -------------------------------- */
    //$('.search-key').on('keyup', findByName);
    /*$('.help-btn').on('click', function() {
        alertjqry("Employee Directory v3.4");
    });*/

 /*
  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {   //window.orientation=='-90' || window.orientation=='90'
    if(window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth){
    if(window.orientation=='-90' || window.orientation=='90')
       alertjqry("Attention: Si vous avez un iphone 6, veuillez retourner en mode portrait sinon certaines fonctions de l'application pourront mal fonctionner avec cette orientation de votre appareil!");
    }else{
          $("#mydialog").dialog('close');
    } 
   }, false);
 */ 


    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
    //console.log(navigator.contacts);
    // console.log(navigator.camera);
  //console.log(FileTransfer);
  //window.open= cordova.InAppBrowser.open;

  //pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
  //destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
/*
    if (navigator.notification) { // Override default HTML alert with native dialog
      window.alert = function (message) {
          navigator.notification.alert(
              message,    // message
              null,       // callback
              "Beezlink", // title
              'OK'        // buttonName
          );
      };
    }

*/ 
   document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

   }, false);

  function onBackKeyDown(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
   }    

   //console.log(FileTransfer);




    /* ---------------------------------- Local Functions ---------------------------------- */


}());
```

Comment: Did you register the event listener??

Comment: Do you mean the deviceready?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: All i have as code is in the one i have posted.

Comment: Take a look ath this website: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html

Comment: That is exactly my reference. I can not see what is missing in my code.

Comment: And you inserted the deviceready code?

Comment: Yes, check my code.

Comment: @PaulNgom Try placing an alert inside onBackKeyDown function and see whether you are getting the alert first

Comment: @Gandhi: i have place the alert but it does not show.

Comment: @PaulNgom This means that your listener itself is not registered properly. Is your device ready event firing atleast?

Comment: How do i check if the device ready event is firing?

Comment: @PaulNgom try placing alert inside your device ready listener and see if its alerting. If it dont, then invoke a function in html body onload and add your deviceready listener code there. Something like <body  onload="onBodyLoad()">  and function onBodyLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

Answer (score 0):

> try adding **e.stopPropagation()** or **e.stopImmediatePropagation()**
>   instead of   e.preventDefault();

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); OR e.stopPropagation();
        }, false );
}
```

> Common mistake is that development is performed on **desktop** and cordova
>   **script is excluded**. One then forgets to **include the cordova script for
>   the mobile version**.

Comment: I have tried it but the app still exits on tap of back button.

Comment: Yes, Akshay. The same problem persists. It exits the app.

Comment: @PaulNgom HAVE YOU INCLUDED CORDOVA.JS IN YOUR PAGE?

Comment: try to include javascript sequence as 1. cordova.js 2.Jquery.js 3.Index.js

Comment: if this not persists your problem then post your html and JS code

Comment: change (function () {} to $(function () {}

Comment: @PaulNgom and plz add eventlistener inside of the $(function(){}) and function outside of it

Comment: I had internet connection problem. I changed the function as you wanted it but the device ready event isn't firing.

Comment: try changing < meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content=".." / >

Comment: is it a line to add in index.html?

Comment: @PaulNgom YES,IT IS

Comment: I have added the meta tag but the problem persists.

Comment: @PaulNgom strange

Answer (score 0):

It's possible u need prevent other event of window like popstate. 
Try this:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
   //try e.preventDefault() or e.stopImmediatePropagation()
   e.stopImmediatePropagation()
   e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I skipped onDeviceReady, so I just have:

```js
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
  function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

And that worked for me